# How do you write media queries for a larger screen than you own?

Tags: html, css

If I am limited to say a 1920 x 1080 screen, how do I create media queries for a larger screen size without being able to test it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set any resolution in Chrome. Just click "Toggle device mode" in Inspector and set any resolution.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Developer Tools, you can [use Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en) to emulate any resolution, not just mobile breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can open the web inspector `Ctrl-Shift-I`, then toggle Device Mode using `Ctrl-Shift-M`. It's mainly used for *smaller* devices, but you should be able to select 'Responsive' in the menu that comes up at the top of the screen, and enter any resolution you wish, along with a zoom level so that you can view it on your screen, albeit scaled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Safari, you can do this relatively easily.

If you aren't using Safari, you probably should get it, at least for website testing. As you can see on step 6, Safari has LOTS of VERY helpful dev tools (i.e. disable JS, disable CSS, etc.).

Here is some instructions with pictures!

---

1. Go to the *Safari* menu (in upper left hand corner).
2. On that menu click *Preferences*, this should open up a pop-up box.

[image]

---

3. On the pop-up box, click the *Advanced* tab.
4. At the very bottom of that tab you should see a checkbox that says *Show Develop menu in menu bar*, check that box.

[image]

---

5. Now load your website in Safari.

---

6. When your website has loaded (for this example I'm using SO), click on the *Develop* dropdown menu.
7. Click *Enter Responsive Design Mode*, and that will now show your website in a window smaller than your browser window.

[image]

---

8. In that window, click on the window looking thing on the far left.
9. There are little gray bars on all sides of that smaller window, if you drag these you can make the size whatever you want.
10. As a side note, when you drag the gray bars (as shown in step 9), you should see the width and height resolution (pixels) change (see screenshot below), this is VERY helpful (and I use it all the time), as it will tell you the exact resolution (pixels) when your website breaks. P.S. you can go to **ANY** screen resolution - big and small - that you want to with this tool, which is really cool! (I've done 2500 x 1500, 100 x 100, etc.)
    [image]

---

Hope this helps you!